# Invoke class getters with use of private members

Tags: javascript, class, private, getter

I have a class like this:

```
export class Test {
  #foo
  #bar

  constructor() {}

  get foo() {
    if (!this.#foo) this.#foo = 1 * 1
    return this.#foo
  }

  get bar() {
    if (!this.#bar) this.#bar = 2 * 2
    return this.#bar
  }
}
```

I need all the getters results in this class so I want to invoke all of them.
I have tried to invoke them outside the class but there are private members in the class so I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read private member #foo from an object whose class did not declare it
```

I have tried to invoke them inside the constructor by looping on `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)` but this don't invoke the getters.

Is there a way I can invoke them inside the class so the getters can use the private members?

Thanks!

Comment: May you show how you're using `Test`?

Comment: I just create an instance of the class: `new Test()` and want to get the results of the getters on the instance (to send those data from server to client).

Comment: If I create an object `t` from `Test`, I can use the getters by `t.foo` and `t.bar` without error

Comment: Can you provide a codepen/sandbox link or a code snippet. I am not able to repro the issue?

Comment: The using is something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-maxwell-jxwif?file=/src/App.js

Comment: > If I create an object t from Test, I can use the getters by t.foo and t.bar without error       

Sure, thanks. But I have a lot of getters and I don't want to invoke them one by one like this, just by looping on all the class members.

Comment: What do you mean? If you need to set up the values in one go, do it in the constructor.

Comment: Tried that but seems the getters aren't invoked in the constructor. Any idea why?
Created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-firefly-d069u?file=/src/Test.js) to demo the flow. Thanks!

Comment: No getters are only invoked when the property is accessed. Why make a getter when you can set the initial values in the constructor?

Comment: This is just an example. I have class with a lot of getters that are full with logics.

Comment: I'm still confused why this logic can't exist in the constructor?